# Charge Transfer and Multireference Methods

Tags: computational-chemistry, spectroscopy, multi-reference

I have read in literature that systems that exhibit "high charge-transfer character" are best treated using multireference/multiconfigurational methods. Why is that? What makes such a system not be adequately described by a single determinant? I understand why singlet biradicals, low-lying HOMO-LUMO gaps, etc, would fall into this category, but why would charge-transfer complexes fall into this category as well?